# Json Parsing failed using Retrofit and moshi -Android

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

This is the error im getting(This is a secondary error and I get this when I use databinding with ListItemView)

```
    import com.example.bookkotlin.databinding.ListViewItemBindingImpl;
                                         ^
  symbol:   class ListViewItemBindingImpl
  location: package com.example.bookkotlin.databinding
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

build.gradle(Project:app)

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.4.20"
        version_glide = "4.8.0"
        version_lifecycle = "2.2.0"
        version_moshi = "1.9.3"
        version_navigation = "1.0.0"
        version_retrofit = "2.9.0"
        version_recyclerview = "1.2.0-alpha05"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id  'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}


android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bookkotlin"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$version_glide"

    // RecyclerView
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$version_recyclerview"

    // Retrofit with Moshi Converter
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$version_retrofit"
    // Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$version_moshi"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$version_moshi"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$version_lifecycle"

    // Navigation
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.0"
}
```

this is BookApiService

```
    package com.example.bookkotlin.network

import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

private const val BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()

interface BookApiService {

    @GET("v1/volumes")
    suspend fun getProperties(@Query("q") type : String) : BookResponse
}

object BookApi {
    val retrofitService : BookApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(BookApiService::class.java) }
}
```

This is BookResponse

```
      package com.example.bookkotlin.network
    
    import android.os.Parcelable
    import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
    
       @Parcelize
data class BookResponse( val items : Array<Items> ) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Items (val id: String,
                  val volumeInfo : BookProperty) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class BookProperty( val authors: Array<String>?, val title: String,
                         val imageLinks: ImageLink) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class ImageLink( val smallThumbnail: String) : Parcelable
```

This is OverviewFragment

```
  package com.example.bookkotlin.overview

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.bookkotlin.R
import com.example.bookkotlin.databinding.FragmentOverviewBinding


class OverviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: OverviewViewModel   by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(OverviewViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


     val binding: FragmentOverviewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
       binding.recyclerList.adapter = RecyclerviewAdapter()

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

I'm calling the API from my OverviewViewModel

```
    package com.example.bookkotlin.overview

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.bookkotlin.network.BookApi
import com.example.bookkotlin.network.BookResponse
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class OverviewViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // Internally, we use a MutableLiveData, because we will be updating the List of MarsProperty
    // with new values
    private val _properties = MutableLiveData<BookResponse> ()

    // The external LiveData interface to the property is immutable, so only this class can modify
    val properties: LiveData<BookResponse>
        get() = _properties

    init {
        getBookProperties()
    }

    private fun getBookProperties() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _properties.value =BookApi.retrofitService.getProperties("Harry Potter")
            } catch (e : Exception) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerviewAdapter

```
  package com.example.bookkotlin.overview

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bookkotlin.databinding.ListViewItemBinding
import com.example.bookkotlin.network.Items


class RecyclerviewAdapter() : ListAdapter<Items, RecyclerviewAdapter.BookPropertyViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookPropertyViewHolder {
        return BookPropertyViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookPropertyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
       val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    class BookPropertyViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ListViewItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

       fun bind(books: Items) {
            binding.property = books
           binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): BookPropertyViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ListViewItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return BookPropertyViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class  DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Items>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Items, newItem: Items): Boolean {
        return oldItem === newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Items, newItem: Items): Boolean {
        return oldItem.volumeInfo.id == newItem.volumeInfo.id

    }
}
```

BindingAdapters

```
  package com.example.bookkotlin

import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.bookkotlin.network.Items
import com.example.bookkotlin.overview.RecyclerviewAdapter


@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: BookResponse) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerviewAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data.items.toList())
}
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String) {
        Glide.with(imgView)
                .load(imgUrl)
                .into(imgView)

}
```

This is list_view_item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="property"
            type="com.example.bookkotlin.network.Items" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
        android:id="@+id/container">
        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_view_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:imageUrl ="@{property.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorAuthor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/author_text_size"
                android:text="@{property.volumeInfo.authors.toString()}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorBookTitle"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                android:text="@{property.volumeInfo.title}"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

fragment_overview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.bookkotlin.overview.OverviewViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context = "com.example.bookkotlin.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchSection"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_view_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:queryHint="Enter a Book Title"
                    tools:queryHint="Enter a Title" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search_book_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Search" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:listData="@{viewModel.properties}"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_view_item"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
            
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
            style="?android:progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Please help me fix the error, I'm still new to Kotlin programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with parsing Json in kotlin and replacing  `List<ObjectType>` with `Array<ObjectType>` wherever required worked for me.

Try the following

```
    @Parcelize
    data class BookResponse( val items : Array<Items> ) : Parcelable
    
      @Parcelize 
     data class Items (val volumeInfo : BookProperty) : Parcelable
    
    
// the volumeinfo returns a JsonObject and that object doesn't contain an **id** field, so remove the **id** member variable from BookProperty
    @Parcelize
    data class BookProperty( val authors: Array<String>?, val title: String, 
   val imageLinks: ImageLink
        ) : Parcelable
    
    @Parcelize
    data class ImageLink( val smallThumbnail: String) : Parcelable
```

Also, the API is just returning one single object and not the list, so make the following changes as well

```
interface BookApiService {

    @GET("v1/volumes")
    suspend fun getProperties(@Query("q") type : String) : BookResponse
}
```

Edit:

You this [formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) to visualize the Json response. For instance when you query the API for `Harry Potter` you are getting a **single** Object and not a list of objects.

**OverviewViewModel**

```
//change the datatype to hold a single object instead of a list

 private val _properties = MutableLiveData<BookResponse>()

 val properties: LiveData<BookResponse>
        get() = _properties
```

**BindingUtils**

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: BookResponse) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerviewAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data.items.toList())
}
```

**Items**

```
@Parcelize
data class Items(val volumeInfo: BookProperty, val id: String) : Parcelable
```

**DiffCallback**

```
class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Items>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Items, newItem: Items): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Items, newItem: Items): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

[data parsed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkF5m.png)

Comment: I changed the code but im getting error in `fragment_overview.xml` ..at `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.. `app:listData="@{viewModel.properties}"`  .The error im getting is `Cannot find a setter for <RecyclerView app:listData> that accepts parameter type 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<com.example.bookkotlin.network.BookResponse>'`.. Man im just stucked in this project . I build the same app in java but when i want to build in kotlin with data binding im getting lots of error. Google codelab didn't showed how to worked with complex JSON in kotlin  @rcs

Comment: the issue is with the binding adapter, the `properties` is a `List<BookResponse>` whereas the binding adapter expects `List<Items>`

Comment: what should i change in binding adapter? .. I'm confused @rcs

Comment: you should change the datatype. That's the error message. I suggest you understand what you doing completely before you do it

Comment: ok i changed the code . When i Gradle Build it im getting error `import com.example.bookkotlin.databinding.ListViewItemBindingImpl;
                                         ^
  symbol:   class ListViewItemBindingImpl
  location: package com.example.bookkotlin.databinding
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`  @rcs

Comment: upate your question with the code you tried so far,

Comment: Done. Have a look at it @rcs

Comment: @Ruhul everything seems to be alright, but not sure whats causing the error, I tried the same on my device and the data was parsed successfully. A quick fix would be not to use databinding for the `ListItemView`

Comment: @Ruhul check the edited answer and go for it if your error still prevails

Comment: I changed the code still getting the same error. Did my code worked fine in your device ? Did you able to parse the book "Harry Potter" ?  @rcs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227593/discussion-between-rcs-and-ruhul).

Comment: Hey, i was able to build it successfully and was able to add the search clicked in the app too. Thank you so much for your help it wouldn't be possible without your help. I have something to ask regarding BindingAdapter and databinding . Can we please discuss it in the discussion chat ? @rcs

Comment: @Ruhul sure, but do check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) before

Comment: i asked the question .. check it out at discussion chat one you have invited me @rcs

Comment: @Ruhul I dont have the link to the chatroom anymore, post  it as a question in stackoverflow?

Comment: it would be really hard to explain to others as a question.. it is from the code of the app that we have been working on yesterday .. I wrote the code using BindingAdapter and data binding and i just want you to check it out, if thatswhy the way i wrote is right or wrong.. Can you make a new link for chat now? and we can talk there ? @rcs

Comment: ok sure, just use the old room, the one in the comments

Comment: hey, I need some help with this question  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871675/how-to-write-this-java-code-to-kotlin-in-binding-adapter] . If you can plzz help me  @Sekiro